# QTP is not identifying frame object

Tags: object, qtp

I am using QTP 9.5. It is not able to identify frame object.I used object spy, when hand goes on frame it recognize as windows explorer, not frame..
Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: Please be specific and to the point.

Comment: then dnt answer, if you didn't get question..Thank You for your answers...

Comment: I am using Stack Overflow. I am not able to identify your question. I used dictionary, but it did not help me to understand what you are asking. Please clarify your question so that people can actually answer it. This is just a bunch of words. What is object spy? What hand? What frame? What frame do you want it to recognize?

Comment: these all words associated to QTP test automation tool..

Comment: What object hierarchy are you getting when you point at the frame? We would expect `Browser/Page/Frame` what are you getting?

Comment: in hierarchy am not getting frame ..which you mentioned

Comment: @Rohit, what **are** you getting? Are you getting a `Window`? `WinObject` or just nothing?

Comment: @Rohit Please could you stop being rude to the people attempting to help you. They are trying to understand your question. They are trying to help.

Comment: @Rohit Please understand that all answers you receive come from people who are taking time out of their day to help you. I've cleaned up a large part of the flame wars in comments, I'd like to not need to do that again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue in QTP9.5 and 10.0 in which all web support is lost when there is a navigation to a JavaScript url (e.g a link with `href="javascript:..."`).

Hotfix QTPWEB_00029 solves this issue (for QTP9.5) you can get this hotfix by contacting HP support.

Another thing that *may* work is to run the undocumented method `Browser("...").RefreshWebSupport`

Answer (score 0):

My experience tells me that QTP 9.5 is unstable and has lot of open issues. I won't be surprised if this happens to be an arbitrary behavior.

Call childobjects() on the page object and check whether the required frame is part of the returned collection. If not, you can also try accessing the properties of the frame using DOM.

Comment: since it is identifying it as windows object, please make sure that web add-in hasn't got disabled. just restart QTP and check the web add in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'get the html DOM obj from the page 
Set pageObj = Browser("eNSQ Window Objects").Page("Additional Information - Type DP - Bad Habits - eNSQ").Object

'get all frames
Set frames = pageObj.getElementsByTagName("frame")

'loop through all frames and msgbox the title
for each thisFrame in frames
   MsgBox thisFrame.title
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you open the window/Browser after you opened QTP?

If that did not work try re-registering QTP dlls by going to the
Start Menu --> Programs --> Quicktest Professional --> Tools --> Additional Installation Requirements
Run that utillity to fix the dlls.

Good luck